# Need help on "setState"

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to write on React. I have a problem - when initializing variables, in "setState" is coming null. My task - display question and his answers in page. I checked callback by fetch, and I get all. My code:

```
    constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                question: "",
                isFetching: true,
                answers: []
            };

            this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            var VariableQuestion;
            var AnswersForQuestion = [];
            fetch('https://localhost:44392/api/QuizData/GetQuestions?numberOfQuestion=1')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(function (result) {

                        VariableQuestion = result.text;
                        var answers = result.allAnswers;
                        for (var z = 0; z < answers.length; z++)
                        {      
                            var ans = answers[z].text;
                            AnswersForQuestion.push(ans);                                                       
                    }
                    console.log(VariableQuestion);

                });

            this.setState({
                question: VariableQuestion,
                isFetching: false,
                answers: AnswersForQuestion
            });

        }


        render() {
            const { question, isFetching, answers } = this.state;

            if (isFetching) return <div>...Loading</div>;

            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>{question}</h1>
                    <h1>{answers}</h1>
                </div>

            )
        } 
}
```

Comment: I think you are running afoul of async javascript, I'll try to answer below

Comment: Yes do the setstate inside the then block.It will work :)

Comment: move setState into the fetch callback, remember that both fetch and setState are async

Comment: Unrelated, but there's no need to bind cDM like this.

Comment: Yes, i thought about it, but i have an error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is an async task. The request function was thrown to the background stack, so your setState got null values since no response has been finished. 
**Just move your setState inside your .then() of the request**, so it waits for the response.
You may want to have a look [here](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/)

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with asynchronous code here, fetch return a promise, so you would set the state once it has been resolved
move your setState inside then block as

```
fetch('https://localhost:44392/api/QuizData/GetQuestions?numberOfQuestion=1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((result) => {

            VariableQuestion = result.text;
            var answers = result.allAnswers;
            for (var z = 0; z < answers.length; z++)
            {      
                var ans = answers[z].text;
                AnswersForQuestion.push(ans);                                                       
        }
        console.log(VariableQuestion);
        this.setState({
         question: VariableQuestion,
         isFetching: false,
         answers: AnswersForQuestion
        });

    });
```

the way you are doing it, setState will run before then block in your code

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, i thought about it, but i have an  error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

This is contrived (and not React) but essentially it helps to explain where the disconnect is.

1. set `data` variable
2. start async
3. log variable
4. finish async and set `data` variable

```js
const asyncData = async () => await setTimeout(() => 'data', 300);

let data = 'nothing';

asyncData().then((res) => { data = res });

console.log(data);
```

so to continue into your code:

```
componentDidMount() {

    fetch('https://localhost:44392/api/QuizData/GetQuestions?numberOfQuestion=1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(function (result) {
        // no reason to have these at the top level 
        // since they only get used here.
        var VariableQuestion = result.text;
        var AnswersForQuestion = [];

        var answers = result.allAnswers;
        for (var z = 0; z < answers.length; z++) {      
          var ans = answers[z].text;
          AnswersForQuestion.push(ans);                                                       
        }
        console.log(VariableQuestion);
        // move this into your async handler.
        this.setState({
          question: VariableQuestion,
          isFetching: false,
          answers: AnswersForQuestion
        });
      });

}
```

Comment: I found my problem - I did not notice that I do not have  .then(result =>

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
var VariableQuestion;
var AnswersForQuestion = [];
fetch('https://localhost:44392/api/QuizData/GetQuestions?numberOfQuestion=1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(function (result) {

    VariableQuestion = result.text;
    var answers = result.allAnswers;
    // for (var z = 0; z < answers.length; z++)
    {
      var ans = answers[z].text;
      AnswersForQuestion.push(ans);
    }
    console.log(VariableQuestion);
    this.setState({
      question: VariableQuestion,
      isFetching: false,
      answers: AnswersForQuestion
    });
  }.bind(this));
}
```